# Adicionar uma linha<tr> antes de outra linha que possua um ID

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso adicionar uma linha  em uma posição específica de uma tabela, utilizando **Javascript**.

Exemplo:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Teste</td></tr>
  <!-- Inserir linha aqui! -->
  <tr id="id_2">
   <td>Teste 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Como exatamente seria isto? Não seria muito mais facil adiciona-lo por html mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando jQuery, pode usar o `insertBefore`, assim:

```
$("<tr><td>Outro teste</td></tr>").insertBefore("#id_2");
```

Ou com Javascript puro, sem jQuery:

```js
var tr = document.createElement("tr"); // cria o elemento tr
var td = document.createElement("td"); // cria o element td
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Outro teste"); 
td.appendChild(textnode); // adiciona o texto na td criada
tr.appendChild(td); // adiciona a td na tr

var tr_id2 = document.getElementById("id_2"); // pega a tr pelo id
// adiciona o elemento criado, a partir do nó pai (no caso <table>)
tr_id2.parentNode.insertBefore(tr, tr_id2);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Teste</td></tr>
  <!-- Inserir linha aqui! -->
  <tr id="id_2">
   <td>Teste 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

O JavaScript tem métodos próprios para tabelas que facilitam isso. Podes juntar uma nova linha simplesmente com

```
var tr = table.insertRow(idIndex);
```

No teu caso podes fazer assim:

```
var idIndex = document.getElementById('id_2').rowIndex;
var table = document.querySelector('table');
var tr = table.insertRow(idIndex);
tr.innerHTML = '<td>Teste intermédio...</td>';
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/puxjewa6/

### Leitura sobre isto (**MDN** <sup>em inglês</sup>):

- [Propriedade tabelas `.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)
- [Propriedade de linhas de tabelas `.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex)